# Android Voice Recording Chart/Graph

Tags: android, voice-recording

I developmented voice recorder with MediaRecorder. And I listening last recorded. I want a voice graph/chart like Google Voice when recording began (Google Speak Now chart)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Visualizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html).

Then checkout this [Github plugin](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer). You can visualize your audio in 4 different forms, see their screenshots.